# Single page site flashes to page 1 before sliding

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have build af little "model" of a single page site i want to build.
On press on a menu item, the site slides down or up, to the page requested.

I do this by having the whole content in a wrapper, that slides up and down with a css animation, and then a javascript to change the animation, depending on where to slide from and to.

But I have this problem, that when pressing on a menu-item, the page is "flashing" to the top page quickly, before doing the animation.

My code looks like this:

index.php:

```
<body>

<div id="menu">
<div id="menu-ele" onclick="slide_page('p1');">P1</div>
<div id="menu-ele" onclick="slide_page('p2');">P2</div>
<div id="menu-ele" onclick="slide_page('p3');">P3</div>
<div id="menu-ele" onclick="slide_page('p4');">P4</div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page1">
<div id="page-titel">Page 1</div>
</div>
<div id="page2">
<div id="page-titel">Page 2</div>
</div>
<div id="page3">
<div id="page-titel">Page 3</div>
</div>
<div id="page4">
<div id="page-titel">Page 4</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu {
    width: 600px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #97B6C7;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #324456;
    border-left: 4px solid #324456;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 8px;
}

#menu-ele {
    width: 110px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #19284B;
    font-family: Trebuchet;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-ele:hover {
    color: #FBFBFB; 
}


#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: wrapper-slide;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    top: 0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wrapper-slide {
}

#page1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #C0595B;
}
#page2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #BCA7A8;
}
#page3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #49677A;
}
#page4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #C0A27B;
}

#page-titel {
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
```

js:

```
function findWebkitRule(rule) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets;

    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {

        for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {

            if (ss[i].cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE && ss[i].cssRules[j].name == rule) {
                return ss[i].cssRules[j];
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}


function change(anim, from, to) {

    var keyframes = findWebkitRule(anim);

    keyframes.deleteRule("0%");
    keyframes.deleteRule("100%");

    keyframes.insertRule("0% { top: " + from + "px; }");
    keyframes.insertRule("100% { top: " + to + "%; }");

    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.webkitAnimationName = anim;
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
}


function slide_page(page) {
    var end = 0;

    if (page == "p1") {
        end = 0;
    }
    if (page == "p2") {
        end = -100;
    }
    if (page == "p3") {
        end = -200;
    }
    if (page == "p4") {
        end = -300;
    }

    var topValue = document.getElementById("wrapper").offsetTop;

    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.webkitAnimationName = "none";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";

    setTimeout(function(){
        change("wrapper-slide", topValue, end);
    }, 300); // <- I set this one to 300, so the flashing problem is demonstrated clearer

}
```

In this example, I have set the setTimeout to 300, så the problem is clearly demonstrated. Normally this would be 0, but you can still se the flash very quickly.

Comment: This could have been easily achieved by jQuery in a better and simple way. Is there a specific reason to use pure JavaScript here?

Comment: I bet it easily could! The rule changing bit is something that i found on the internet - couldn't find anything similar in jQuery that worked.. that's why pure js... Any links to some jQuery that could help me here, will be gladly appreciated! :)

Comment: I can make the same stuff in jQuery, if you give me some time. `:)`

Comment: That would be awesome! :D

Comment: Have a look at my snippet. Sorry for the time taken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Using jquery animate to slide to the relevant page.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function slide_page(page) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+page).offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu {
    width: 600px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #97B6C7;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #324456;
    border-left: 4px solid #324456;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 8px;           
}

#menu-ele {
    width: 110px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #19284B;
    font-family: Trebuchet;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-ele:hover {
    color: #FBFBFB; 
}


#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: wrapper-slide;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    top: 0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wrapper-slide {
}

#page1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #C0595B;
}
#page2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #BCA7A8;
}
#page3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #49677A;
}
#page4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #C0A27B;
}

#page-titel {
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 25%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="menu">
<div id="menu-ele" onclick="slide_page('page1');">P1</div>
<div id="menu-ele" onclick="slide_page('page2');">P2</div>
<div id="menu-ele" onclick="slide_page('page3');">P3</div>
<div id="menu-ele" onclick="slide_page('page4');">P4</div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page1">
<div id="page-titel">Page 1</div>
</div>
<div id="page2">
<div id="page-titel">Page 2</div>
</div>
<div id="page3">
<div id="page-titel">Page 3</div>
</div>
<div id="page4">
<div id="page-titel">Page 4</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works really well :D and with a lot less code ;) thanks. - but now the menu slides with the content... any tips on how to prevent that? position: fixed or absolute didnt do it..

Comment: I adjusted the CSS so the menu stayed fixed to the top of the page; I have reverted this now back to your original CSS, so the menu scrolls with the content.

Comment: @Ziltoid No offence, but did you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following snippet to convert it into a SPA.

- This works in any size.
- Header stays fixed.
- Body shows only one frame at a time.
- More important, **no flickering**!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".page").css({
    height: $(window).height(),
    lineHeight: $(window).height() + "px"
  });
  $("nav a").click(function () {
    theHref = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(theHref).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
a {color: #33f; text-decoration: none;}

body {overflow: hidden;}

header {position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;}
header nav ul {padding: 5px; background: #ccf; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;}
header nav ul li {display: inline-block;}
header nav ul li a {display: block; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
header nav ul li a:hover {background-color: #99f; color: #fff;}

.page {text-align: center;}
#page-1 {background: #99f;}
#page-2 {background: #9f9;}
#page-3 {background: #f99;}
#page-4 {background: #9cf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#page-1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page-2">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page-3">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page-4">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section>
  <div class="page" id="page-1">Page 1</div>
  <div class="page" id="page-2">Page 2</div>
  <div class="page" id="page-3">Page 3</div>
  <div class="page" id="page-4">Page 4</div>
</section>
```

**JSBin: http://jsbin.com/rekobofami, http://output.jsbin.com/rekobofami**